# Math odds versus gambling odds

Tags: probability, definition, gambling

As far as I remember the mathematical concept *odds* is defined as:

> the probability something is true divided by the probability that it is not.

Or as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) puts it:

> the ratio of the probability that the event will happen to the probability that the event will not happen.

However, reading about odds in sports gambling, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) says this:

> In gambling, odds represent the ratio between the amounts staked by parties to a wager or bet. Thus, odds of 6 to 1 mean the first party (normally a bookmaker) stakes six times the amount staked by the second party.

Which implies that assuming the bet is *fair* that the quoted "odds" are actually $\frac{1}{P(E)}$ where $E$ is the event you are betting on. This understanding is confirmed by an answer on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140284/38379) (which doesn't assume fairness).

> The odds you have are in decimal format, which the bookmaker
>   calculates as:
>
> $$ d_E = \frac{1}{p_E + o_E} $$
>
> where $d_E$ is the decimal odds for event $E$, $p_E$ is the bookmakers
>   estimated probability of event $E$, and $o_E$ is the [over-round](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/140284/38379)
>   which the bookmaker adds to the decimal odds for event $E$.

So even assuming $o = 0$ for all the $o$'s, then the bookmakers odds aren't really "odds" in the sense of $\frac{P(E)}{P(\neg E)}$ but instead $\dfrac{1}{P(E) }$. Thus the word *odds* is going around with more than one meaning. Correct?

Comment: Odds are not the reciprocal of probability!  A fair quote of $a:b$ for the odds makes the probability $\frac a{a+b}$.

Comment: The wiki article has the right flavor.  In the old peri mutuel system (with no spread taken by the house) you just throw in a dollar for which ever side you favor, and the odds are then #dollars for vs #dollars against.

Comment: @lulu the odds that I am seeing are just a single number like $2.5$ which I guess makes $a =1$...

Comment: Ok, "decimal odds" is not the same as, say, "American odds".  Gambling vocabulary is (intentionally, I think) confusing.  As I understand decimal odds they include the stake.  Thus $1:1$ would correspond to the decimal $2$.  So, to your original question, people do use the words "odds" in multiple ways.  Context is critical.

Comment: Look up the moneyline system if you really want to be confused.  And that's the dominant quotation system for lots of main stream betting in the U.S.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. My original question boils down to the question "Am overlooking something or are do people do use the words "odds" in multiple ways".

Comment: Right, and you are correct.  Decimal odds are very seldom quoted in the States, can't think when I last saw them.  People either quote peri mutuel odds (as in $3:1$) or they quote American odds as in the money line system.  Easy to convert from one to the other, but I agree it gets confusing.